# Drop down text like on this particular website

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I know this is a really broad question, but when I try to google it all I get is the answer for a drop down menu.

I'm looking for the code for the dropdown text like it's done [here](http://www.peacecorps.gov/index.cfm?shell=learn.howvol.faq) when you click on a question. Or at least a name so I can google more specifically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a Fiddle with the code to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/Zy4gW/

HTML:

```
<ul id="q-and-a">
    <li><a>Question One</a>
      <div>Answer to Question One...</div>
    </li>
    <li><a>Question Two</a>
      <div>Answer to Question Two...</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
ul li { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; }
ul li a { color: blue; }
ul li div { display: none; }
```

JQuery:

```
$(function(){

  $('#q-and-a li a').each(function(){
      $(this).click(function(){
          $(this).siblings('div').slideToggle(300);            
      });        
  });                

});​​
```

You probably don't need a plugin for something this simple. Just setup the right structure and then show/hide the 'reveal' content.

Comment: Thanks, it's working great. Is there a way I can link to question 2 for example and when you click the link the text is already open?

Comment: Do you mean like bringing someone onto the page and already have one opened? I.E. http://www.yoursite.com/faqs#question2 would already have #2 in the opened state?

Comment: Here's the code to do that: http://jsfiddle.net/Zy4gW/1/ - notice you'll need to add id's to the answer div's and a bit more jQuery goodness...

Answer (score 2):

That's what you call an *accordion*, and [jQueryUI has one](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/). By default, it doesn't act like the one in the website, but it can be configured to act the same way.

Comment: That looks pretty good, can you link to the diffrent sections? Say, I want to have Section 2 open when I open the site, is that possible?